# logging spring specific logs using log4j

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I'm using spring 5.3.7, log4j 1.2.7 without maven and Tomcat 9. I have configured log4j using the log4j.properties file to log all the results to a log.out file. I'm able to view my custom logs in the log.out file. My question is how do I log the results generated by spring (e.g.: Bean initialization, Bean exceptions etc.) to my log.out file.

Following are the contents of my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}\\mylogs\\log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: You will have to create a logger within your code. This [article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spring-logging/) will help.

Comment: I have already configured log4j for my project, I just want to log the spring specific logs to my log.out file